# Working with local storage on AngularJS for shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I'm just starting out to build a simple shopping cart using AngularJS. I've now completed all the CRUD operations for the cart and now want to persist the cart for 3 days using local storage. I also want to be able to check local storage and retrieve cart when user visits the site again. Below is my code. Any help will be appreciated;

**JS code**

```
$scope.items = <?php echo json_encode($item_array); ?>;
$scope.cart = [];
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
  var cart = $scope.cart;
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match.count) {
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
    return;
  }
}

$scope.addItem = function(item) {
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match) {
    match.count += 1;
    return;
  }
  var itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
  itemToAdd.count = 1;
  $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
}

$scope.incQty = function(item) {
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match) {
    match.count += 1;
    return;
  }
}

$scope.decQty = function(item) {
  var cart = $scope.cart;
  var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
  if (match.count > 1) {
    match.count -= 1;
    return;
  }
  cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
}

$scope.subTotal = function() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0, max = $scope.cart.length; i < max; i++) {
    subtotal += $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].count;
  }
  $scope.subtotal = subtotal;
}

$scope.calcTotal = function() {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0, max = $scope.cart.length; i < max; i++) {
    total += $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].count;
  }
  $scope.total = total + $scope.qwickCharge;
}
```

In my HTML i'm using `ng-repeat` to list out items and `ng-repeat` to list out cart array items. The CRUD is done using `ng-click` to call the functions.

That all works perfect. I now just need to be able to make `$scope.cart`persistent in localStorage. Check if localStorage has a cart data and load them for users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On startup, you can ask if localStorage is available:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
```

If it is available, you can check if you already saved data for the user:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
  if(checkDate(localStorage.getItem("lastSave"))) {
    $scope.cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
  } else {
    $scope.cart = {};
  }
}
```

The function checkDate() should check, if the data is still fresh or if 3 days are over and you need to load new data

If the user is done and presses save or something like that, you just override his old data and save the current date:

```
localStorage.setItem("cart", $scope.cart);
localStorage.setItem("lastSave", new Date().getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

CheckDate() could look like this:

```
function checkDate(date) {
  if(date < new Date().getTime()) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Notice the change when i save the date, i now calculate the day 3 days away from today. Then in checkDate() you just check if the saved date (which is 3 days ahead) is less the date we have today. if it is less, 3 days are over and you have to get a new cart. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Any idea how the `checkDate()` function will look like?

Comment: Edited my question, notice the change i made to the point where i save the date to the local storage.

Comment: Great this works perfect. From a shopping cart point of view is this secure? Do I need to store anything in cookies (for reference)?

Comment: The question is, what means secure to you? The user can view the loaclStorage (Chrome: F12 -> Ressources -> Local Storage), its a great way to save the users preferences, in your case their shopping cart, but to make it secure i would send everything to a server and process it there. So in the end you have, on one side the localStorage so you can load the cart for the user fast without a server, and on the other side you have everything saved to your server where you process the order so the user can't do fancy things with his cart like change prices and stuff.

Comment: Alright. Sure, all order processing and validation will be done server side with PHP